# How to stop NavigationView automatically focus on AutoSuggest box?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Currently, my home page looks somewhat like this.

```
<NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="True" PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal">
        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox/>
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
</NavigationView>
```

It is just a NavigationView in a split view tab style with a search bar.

The problem is that whenever I tap on the hamburger menu the menu pane is open and automatically focus on the AutoSuggestBox. It does not seem to be much of a problem on a Desktop But on a phone? It pops up a touch keyboard. Which is infuriating (for me). Is there a way to stop it?

I tried myself with just this...

```
//Home.xaml
<NavigationView PaneOpening="STOP" IsSettingsVisible="True" PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal">
        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="search"/>
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
</NavigationView>
//Home.xaml.cs
private void mainPanel_PaneOpening(WINUI.NavigationView sender, object args) 
    => search.Focus(FocusState.Unfocused);
```

It didn't work as it threw an error and crash.

And I also tried moving it to PaneOpenned event instead...

```
private void mainPanel_PaneOpened(WINUI.NavigationView sender, object args) 
    => search.Focus(FocusState.Unfocused);
```

And it still crash.

Comment: I misunderstood the use of this control. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Phone? what phone device that test with ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT sorry for the late reply, but the phone I tested on is Lumia 950

Comment: As for as I know Lumia950 does not support `NavigationView` that is contained in 
windows sdk 16299.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'm aware of that, but I use a WinUILib which bring support to older version of windows back to anniversary update. :/

Comment: Could you share a mini sample that could reproduce this issue.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Here is the mimalist version:
**1** Create new UWP project and set min version to Anniversary Update
**2** Import "Microsoft.UI.Xaml" from nuget
**3** Follow the readme instruction
**4** Go to "MainPage.xaml" and put a using 'xmlns:wui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls'
**5** Replace grid with this
'<wui:NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal">
    <wui:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="Search" />
    </wui:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
</wui:NavigationView>'
*6* Deploy app into phone and open the navigation button

Comment: Which version `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` about  you have used?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT 2.0.181011001-prerelease